# Getting an exception: "NotImplementedException: PropVariant VT_EMPTY"

Tags: c#, windows, core-audio, naudio

I am using Naudio to handle the audio session and device changes When connecting or disconnecting a headset or Bluetooth device, sometimes I am getting an exception: "NotImplementedException: PropVariant VT_EMPTY". I couldn't find reason for this problem is anyone handled this?

I am using the MMNotificationClient interface to detect the change in the default audio device

Answer (score 1):

Support for VT_EMPTY has been added to the NAudio codebase but not been released yet. Hopefully will resolve this issue once released.

Comment: When will except the new release and is there any chance to get updated NAudio library with mentioned changes?